# Is it possible to make call out titles in blender?

Tags: animation, mesh

I mean some like this. In youtube a lot of videos about dat trick but only for after effects -_- no one guide for blender.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAQGWi8oT0U 
Here is a good example.

[image]

Comment: You should be able too. Please ask something that we would be able to give an example of how to do

Comment: man a u fakin jester? of course i mean how to do it, but english not my mine language so its hard for me make correct sentence

Comment: Yes, look for tutorials on motion graphics, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9uIYJeHcKM)